# openapi swagger ui not passing Authorization in request headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

iam trying to test api using swagger UI. but **Authorization** request header is not getting added to request headers. But correlationId is getting added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is the `Authorization` header defined in your code? It must be defined as a [security scheme](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#security-annotations), not a header parameter.

Comment: @Helen thanks for advice. this helped me. I created swagger.yml added security schema. then tis working.